# Web scraping com R

Tags: r, web-scraping

Estou tentanto fazer um Web Scrapping do seguinte link: http://empresasdobrasil.com/empresas/alta-floresta-mt/

Eu quero acessar todas as categorias e extrair um data frame com o nome de todas as empresas.

Se vocês clicarem no nome de alguma das empresas vai ter alguns dados como:

- Nome fantasia
- Razão Social
- Data da abertura
- Status da empresa
- Natureza jurídica
- Endereço

Gostaria de além dos nomes, como obter essas informações também.

Tentei utilizar o `rvest` mas não tive sucesso.

Alguma ideia?

Comment: Parceiro,
vc tem que criar uma função para raspar os links da primeira camada (categorias) e para cada item da categoria faça o mesmo para o link das empresas. Recomendo utilizar RSelenium pois a navegação pode ser aliada às listas de links. Faça raspagem em loop para cada endereçamento da lista. Abs,

Comment: Eu estava fazendo um script para responder a sua pergunta, mas dei de cara com isso: [Screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/3brNp.png). O site não permite acesso em massa, e qualquer tentativa vai fazer com que você caia no captcha. A não ser que você saiba (ou descubra) uma maneira de resolve-lo, o caminho é comprar os serviços que eles oferecem.

Comment: Ah, e se você insistir, como eu estava fazendo aqui, vai chegar aqui: [http://empresasdobrasil.com/acessoBloqueado](http://empresasdobrasil.com/acessoBloqueado). Aí nem captcha resolve.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

O meu acesso foi bloqueado enquanto estava fazendo, mas meu codigo acabou ficando como abaixo. Tem algumas explicacoes de como funciona cada parte. Usei somente pacotes contemporaneos do Hadley Wickham, incluindo o `rvest` que vc queria usar.

Infelizmente o scraper não é tão útil por conta do captcha e dos bloqueios. O site permite fazer orçamentos [aqui](http://empresasdobrasil.com/orcamento/cadastrar). O código abaixo pode ser usado pra outros scrapers. Recomendo que faça um tratamento mais legal de erros, por exemplo usando `dplyr::failwith` ou `tryCatch`.

```
library(rvest)
library(httr)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

#' Tem captcha?
#'
#' Verifica se uma resposta tem captcha
#'
#' @param r resultado de uma request (pacote \code{\link{httr}}).
#'
#' @return \code{TRUE} se tiver captcha e \code{FALSE} caso contrário.
tem_captcha <- function(r) {
  res <- r %>%
    content('text') %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes(xpath = '//form[@action="/verificarCaptcha/confirmar"]') %>%
    length()
  res > 0
}

bloqueado <- function(r) {
  r %>%
    content('text') %>%
    str_detect('Acesso bloqueado')
}

#' Baixar categorias
#'
#' Baixa as categorias a partir do link inicial
#' ex.: http://empresasdobrasil.com/empresas/alta-floresta-mt/
#'
#' @param link URL do município.
#'
#' @return \code{data.frame}
baixar_categorias <- function(link) {
  r <- GET(link)
  if (r$status_code != 200) return(data.frame(result = 'erro'))
  if (tem_captcha(r)) return(data.frame(result = 'captcha'))
  if (bloqueado(r)) return(data.frame(result = 'bloqueado'))
  u_base <- 'http://empresasdobrasil.com'
  r %>%
    content('text') %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_nodes('.container a.linhas') %>% {
      data.frame(tipo = html_text(.),
                 link_categoria = paste0(u_base, html_attr(., 'href')),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    } %>%
    mutate(result = 'OK')
}

#' Baixar empresas
#'
#' Baixa as empresas a partir do link de uma categoria
#' ex.: http://empresasdobrasil.com/empresas/alta-floresta-mt/hoteis
#'
#' @param link URL da categoria
#'
#' @return \code{data.frame}
baixar_empresas <- function(link) {
  r <- GET(link, write_disk('arq.html', overwrite = TRUE))
  if (r$status_code != 200) return(data.frame(result = 'erro'))
  if (tem_captcha(r)) return(data.frame(result = 'captcha'))
  if (bloqueado(r)) return(data.frame(result = 'bloqueado'))
  u_base <- 'http://empresasdobrasil.com'
  r %>%
    content('text') %>%
    read_html() %>%
    html_node('table') %>% {
      tab <- html_table(.) %>%
        setNames('nome_razao') %>%
        separate(nome_razao, c('nome_fantasia', 'razao_social'),
                 sep = ' - ', extra = 'merge', fill = 'left')
      links <- html_nodes(., 'a') %>%
        html_attr('href')
      tab$link_empresa <- paste0(u_base, links)
      tab
    } %>%
    mutate(result = 'OK')
}

#' Baixar infos de uma empresa
#'
#' Baixa as empresas a partir do link de uma categoria
#' ex.: http://empresasdobrasil.com/empresas/alta-floresta-mt/hoteis
#'
#' @param link URL da categoria
#'
#' @return \code{data.frame}
baixar_empresa <- function(link) {
  r <- GET(link)
  if (r$status_code != 200) return(data.frame(result = 'erro'))
  if (tem_captcha(r)) return(data.frame(result = 'captcha'))
  if (bloqueado(r)) return(data.frame(result = 'bloqueado'))
  r %>%
    content('text') %>%
    read_html() %>% {
      data.frame(titulo = html_text(html_nodes(., 'h4')),
                 texto = html_text(html_nodes(., 'h5')),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    } %>%
    mutate(result = 'OK')
}

baixar_tudo <- function(link) {
  link <- 'http://empresasdobrasil.com/empresas/alta-floresta-mt/'
  d <- link %>%
    baixar_categorias() %>%
    group_by(tipo, link_categoria) %>%
    do(baixar_empresas(.$link_categoria)) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    group_by(tipo, link_categoria, nome_fantasia,
             razao_social, link_empresa) %>%
    do(baixar_empresa(.$link_empresa))
  d
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Você só precisa da library XML para raspar os dados.

O código abaixo funcionou para capturar info das primeiras empresas. Porém, fui bloqueado por excesso de acessos. Se você superar essa barreira, o código funciona.

Em primeiro lugar, capturei os links de todas as categorias. A seguir, em cada categoria, os links de cada empresa. Finalmente, com um for loop, vc raspa a página de cada empresa, extrai os dados que estão na tag  e insere como nova linha num data frame vazio.

```
library(XML)

url <- "http://empresasdobrasil.com/empresas/alta-floresta-mt/"
page_source <- xmlRoot(htmlParse(readLines(url)))
links_categorias<- xpathSApply(page_source, "//a[@class = 'linhas']", xmlGetAttr, name = "href")

url_parcial <- "http://empresasdobrasil.com/"
links_empresas <- c()
i = 1
for (categoria in links_categorias){
print(i); i = i + 1
url <- paste0(url_parcial, categoria)
page_source <- xmlRoot(htmlParse(readLines(url)))
links <- xpathSApply(page_source, "//td/a[@href]", xmlGetAttr, name = "href")
  links_empresas <- c(links_empresas, links)
}

i = 1
dados <- data.frame()
for (empresa in links_empresas){
print(i); i = i + 1
url <- paste0(url_parcial, empresa)
page_source <- xmlRoot(htmlParse(readLines(url)))
info_empresa <- xpathSApply(page_source, "//h5", xmlValue)
  dados <- rbind(dados, info_empresa)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

O RSelenium é uma boa idéia. Embora não precisa carregar pagina, basta usar as funções do pacote XML (htmlParse, getNodeSet, xmlValue e xmlGetAttr)

1 - coletar todos os links dos setores;

2 - coletar os links  das empresas (precisa de um loop, com links do passo anterior)

3 - coletar os dados das empresas (loop com links do passo anterior)