# Web scraping em websites aplicativos no R

Tags: r

Gostaria de saber algumas ideias para obter os dados deste link: http://relatorios.aneel.gov.br/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/RelatoriosSAS/RelSAMPClasseConsNivel.xlsx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frelatorios%2Eaneel%2Egov%2Ebr%2FRelatoriosSAS%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1

Utilizei o codigo abaixo para tentar extrair os dados. Mas quando entro com CSS do que quero extrair, ele devolve o html nodes vazio.

```
rm(list = ls())
#install.packages("rvest")
library(rvest)

url <- paste0("http://relatorios.aneel.gov.br/_layouts/xlviewer.aspx?id=/RelatoriosSAS/RelSAMPClasseConsNivel.xlsx&Source=http%3A%2F%2Frelatorios%2Eaneel%2Egov%2Ebr%2FRelatoriosSAS%2FForms%2FAllItems%2Easpx&DefaultItemOpen=1")

#Reading the HTML code from the website
webpage <- read_html(url)

#Using CSS selectors to scrap the rankings section
rank_data_html <- html_nodes(webpage,'.cv-nwl')
```

Gostaria de enfatizar que o site não está no formato padrão que geralmente temos para extração de dados da internet, ou seja html. Ele parece algo como um aplicativo. Alguém teria uma ideia de como extrair esses dados?

Comment: Isso resolve http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109475/3635 ?

Comment: Estes dados parecem estar dentro de uma planilha do Excel. Não é possível baixar a planilha diretamente?

Comment: É possível, o problema é que existem um formulário lá em cima que você dá o que você quer.

Comment: Por favor, explique o que tentou e os problemas que encontrou.

Comment: Isso ajuda pelo menos no começo http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109475/3635? Estou votando como ampla demais pois não tem muita coisa a ser feita e não foi apresentado código ou tentativa. Não é necessariamente uma duplicata.

Comment: Não seria possível baixar o arquivo `.xlsx` e fazer o parser do mesmo?

Comment: Na verdade, a questão é que eu gostaria de pegar os resultados de cada mês para cada ano. Então eu teria que baixar diversos xlsx, pois é um novo arquivo gerado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento a solução do link  pt.stackoverflow.com/q/109475/3635 não ajuda, pois a pagina que eu gostaria de raspar é como se fosse um aplicativo do Excel. Eu teria que entrar os dados do formulario para extrair os valores. Teria outra explicação?

Comment: Nossa, faz um ano :) ... então, o que você deseja é ler as colunas e linhas de uma planilha então este pacote deve resolver o seu problema: https://github.com/tidyverse/readxl

Comment: Não, na verdade o excel abre nesse link que eu enviei anteriormente como se fosse um site na internet.

Comment: @morebru aquilo ali é populado dinamicamente via Ajax, não vai ter como fazer nada ali, a não ser que use algo como [**PhantomJS**](http://phantomjs.org), mas é muito trabalho que pode ser resolvido de outra forma, se você selecionar file e download em seguida vai gerar este link: https://pastebin.com/raw/XFAUYbtZ (o link que esta dentro deste link, é que não cabe nos comentários)